# LINQ Query search List within another List and return value

Tags: c#, list, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

Hi I am just trying to get the structure correct before re-writing some old Javascript code to C#.

I have a List of CanDetails which I need to be able to search within for a ByteName and get its BytePos value.

I am struggling with the query to be able to pull out BytePos with my linqQuery I am hoping to just be able to get the integer value returned only if possible.

Stripped down example below with my attempt at the LinQ which all works.

Problem is I am returning in my result a CanDetails object and still will need to search within that again to find the BtyePos I am looking for.

Many thanks in advance.

```
    public class ByteData
{
    public string ByteName { get; set; }
    public int BytePos { get; set; }
}

public class CanDetails
{
    public string CanName { get; set; }
    public int CanID { get; set; }
    public List<ByteData> ByteStuff { get; set; }
    public int[] RawData { get; set; }
}

public class test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<CanDetails> CanIDs = new List<CanDetails>();

        CanIDs.Add(new Models.CanDetails()
        {
            CanName = "test",
            CanID = 11,
            ByteStuff = new List<ByteData>() {
                new ByteData { ByteName = "james", BytePos = 0 },
                new ByteData { ByteName = "bob", BytePos = 1 },
            },
            RawData = new int[8] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 }
        });

        var linqQuery = CanIDs.Where(o => o.ByteStuff.Any(x => x.ByteName == "james")).Select(x => x.ByteStuff).First();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the issue with this code? Does it give any error? What unexpected output you are getting? What output you are expecting?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya the code works, but I am unable to run a Linq Query searching on ByteName within CanID's and return the found BytePosition. The last line Var linqQuery is where I am struggling.

Comment: Does it give any error? What value you get in `linqQuery`?

Comment: @SamIam that will return a CanDetails object which I will still need to search to find the BytePos for the initial Search against a ByteName

Comment: This may not be the most elegant way of doing it but it seems to work: `var linqQuery = CanIDs.Select(o => o.ByteStuff.Where(x => x.ByteName == "james")).First().First().BytePos;`

Comment: @mrogers Thanks you hit the nail on the head, much appreciated to everyone for taking the time to read and reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flatten the multiple `List<ByteData>` using `SelectMany` into one list. Then select the element you need and access the `BytePos`. If no matching element is found, return `null`.

```
 var linqQuery = CanIDs
     .SelectMany(c => c.ByteStuff)
     .FirstOrDefault(b => b.ByteName == "james")
     ?.BytePos;
```

[C# Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SLoUGB)

Comment: Thank you Georg this works and also catches the default Null which I would normally have in place.

Comment: Glad i can help :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is to run this LINQ expression:

```
var byteData = CanIDs
                .SelectMany(can => can.ByteStuff)
                .FirstOrDefault(byteData => byteData.ByteName == "james");
```

If you write on output byteData.BytePos then it will print '0' as number.

### What's going on inside query?

#### SelectMany

When I selected ByteStuff from all of your can IDs then you can Imagine that after this statement you are working on collection that is union of all ByteStuff Collections that were inside your list.

#### FirstOrDefault

I am trying to find object in collection that passes given condition. It returns null if it will do not find any object.

I hope that it is the answer that you were looking for.

Comment: thanks for the taking time to reply, but I was explicitly trying to return the BytePos within in one Query.